# arrumar diretório

Tags: c++

Gostaria de saber como adicionar o nome do usuario onde esta em aspas escrito "devo colocar o nome do usuário aqui"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<lmcons.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
//User Name
TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;

GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &username_len);

wcout << username << endl;

//Computer name
TCHAR compname[UNCLEN + 1];
DWORD compname_len = UNCLEN + 1;

GetComputerName((TCHAR*)compname, &compname_len);

wcout << compname << endl;

cin.get();

system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v formula /d C://users//"DEVO COLOCAR O NOME DO USUARIO AQUI"//downloads//formula.exe");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de fazer o que pretende. De entre as várias mostro duas.

### sprintf

Com [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) consegue interpolar uma `string` com quaisquer valores que queira. Precisa primeiro de construir a `string` em forma de `char[]` que irá levar o texto final e de seguida chamar `sprintf` sobre ela:

```
char username[] = "carlos";
char cmd[200];
sprintf(cmd, "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v formula /d C://users//%s//downloads//formula.exe", username);

system(cmd);
```

Olhe atentamente para o texto utilizado no `sprintf` que tem `%s` no local onde é colocado o nome.

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/72IAKv)

### Concatenação de `string`

Utilizando o operador `+` sobre uma `string` de c++ consegue concatenar um `char[]` diretamente, tornando todo o processo fácil também:

```
char username[] = "carlos";
string cmd = "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /t REG_SZ /v formula /d C://users//";
cmd += username;
cmd += "//downloads//formula.exe";

system(cmd.c_str());
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/kQdtlv)

Esta versão tem algumas diferenças a salientar. O comando é construido como `string` e não `char[]`. Por este motivo a chamada ao `system` que é suposto passar o `char*` tem de ser com `cmd.c_str()` para obter a `string` em formato `char[]`.